# How to make sure the API request is made from the certain person who can do that?

Tags: php, javascript, json, api, cryptography

I am creating an API for my website which has lots of information, for say, movies. I want to allow certain number of requests. So, for example, 5$ plan allows 10,000 requests a month. User sign ups, gets the API key and then can make a request like

`http://website.com/index.php?api_key=API_KEY&movie=Titanic`

and the server gives back the answer in `json`. My question now is, how can I make sure that this API_KEY can be used just by that user? Because if he makes an AJAX request, someone else can see the link with the API_KEY and use it for his project. And I want to allow AJAX requests.

Comment: you can do like google does: register the key with a particular domain, and check the domain upon API access. yes, referrers can be spoofed, but not by JS alone, and if someone has something that can spoof, they don't need to hijack your js API...

Comment: see this may help http://www.preact.io/api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever holds that `API_KEY` should be considered "that user", so if you want to keep "atomic" requests (where `api_key` is part of each request, and no request need to depend on previous ones) then you can't really do much about it. But you can try then other approach where you  change the way your API works, by getting rid of said "atomicness". In that model it would require any api method to call with `session_key` instead of the `api_key`, and your `api_key` should only be used to generate **temporary** `session_key` (kind of `login` but for API - say `login` method there). Then all further calls should require session_key `login` returned. In that case you can control (and limit) the number of sessions created with the single `api_key`, or i.e. terminate other sessions if new `login` is called.

Comment: There's no perfect solution but this approach solves most of the problems. And you can easily detect that certain key is compromised - if you see too many force logouts from different IPs that looks suspictious (the same IP is fine - someone may be testing their code etC). And you can always let customer regenerate own api key, so if such problem occur, he can invalidate old api key by getting new one. Problem solved :)

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on your intention for the API key. In your solution, does the end user (the one making the AJAX request) ever see the API key? Or do they only see the session key, and the API key stays on the clients server (the person who purchased access to the API)?

Comment: It depends on your implementation and API. you can easily make API not\ checking callee's IP on `login` (session key creation), but check for all other calls. That would let you keep api_key in your scripts hosted on server (i.e. PHP or whatever). In such case your AJAX first calls your script to obtain session key, and then uses it to call the API directly. First call to api with certain session key binds IP of callee to the session.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try sending your API_KEY in custom headers which can be triggered along with php or ajax requests from the client side, that way your API_KEY is not visible in the URL at all, later which can be ripped of from the server using `apache_request_headers()`, it is a much safer approach, if you are still not satisified you can implement HMAC http authentication, which is damn safe, I bet you.

**Approach 1:(without HMAC)**

**Client Side:**

*using Jquery*

`$.ajax({`
    `url: 'foo/bar',`
    `headers: { 'api_key': 'API_KEY' }`
`});`

*Using PHP*

`header('api_key':'API_KEY');`

by adding header with the request the URL can be just

`http://website.com/index.php?movie=Titanic`

**On serverside:**

`$headers = apache_request_headers();`
`if(isset($headers['api_key']))`
  `{`
  `// validate your api_key from database`
   `}`

**Approach 2: (with HMAC)**
In this case, there is a slight change, instead of sending API_KEY in your url as query string , you will have to send userID or any other unique identifier, inorder which is related to the api_key in your database.

**on client side:**

do HMAC as given in `https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC`

or using php function `hash_hmac()`
using both methods you will get a hashed value which is a combination of your API_KEY , and your data
eg. 
`$hashed_value = hash_hmac('sha1','titanic','API_KEY');`
`header('hash':$hashed_value);`

your url `http://website.com/index.php?movie=Titanic&uid=xx`

**On server side:**

`$headers = apache_request_headers();`
`if(isset($headers['hash']))`
  `{`
  `// then try to recreate your hash in server, like`
   `//using $_GET['uid']= get your API_KEY from DB`
    `$api_key = getApiKey($_GET['uid']);`
    `$hash = hash_hmac('sha1',$_GET['movie'],$api_key);`
    `if($hash==$headers['hash'])`
     `{`
     `// User authenticated`
   }

`}`

If you go through [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), you can figure out its benefits.

Comment: Headers can still be read. All the user needs to do is examine the request in something like firebug or google chrome's built in dev tool.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that the header data is still visible in dev. tools of browsers, but still using approach 2, it makes it secure than making it vulnerable. I think that you know that Hash is not going to be decoded easily unless, the hacker know the api_key.

Answer (score 2):

If the API key is made visible on the client in any way, shape or form, users who visit that page can also make requests on the API user's behalf, as long as they are "power user" enough to inspect the code and/or HTTP requets. Regardless of whether you have encryption, whether you accept the key in the URL, cookie or whatever... Those other methods may be a slight inconvinience, but a user that knows enough to start searching for the API key is likely also knowedable enough to have heard about Fiddler and the like.

This is the very reason why APIs typically don't make themselves available to JavaScript (i.e. AJAX), but only to direct requests - the server will be the one making the request, and thus it wouldn't need to reveal their API key to its users that way.

There's simply no solution to this, short of not allowing AJAX to use the API. The only kind of an API you should allow AJAX access to is a publically available API (as in "no login required"), limited only by IP making N amount of requests in N amount of time instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using just (effectively public) API keys. What you need is cryptographic authentication with secret keys. [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) with client side certificates ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a 100% perfect solution but for your particular movie business example it should work out just fine.

First you give each user a username and password.

In order to make an AJAX call user will have to specify 3 things:

1. username
2. desired movie id
3. API_KEY

Now, the API_KEY will be a hash (you can use `sha1()` or `md5()` or even a combination of them) that is generated based on:

- user's password
- desired movie id
- today's date

So here's approximately what user will have to do in order to make an AJAX request:

```
$username = 'john_smith';
$password = 'abc';
$movie_id = 'Titanic';
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$API_KEY = sha1($password . $movie_id . $date);

AJAX("http://website.com/index.php?user=$user_name&movie=$movie_id&api_key=$API_KEY");
```

(Similar can be done in JavaScript in case you are expecting users to only have client side environment.)

On your side you will have to do as follows. Knowing the username you find out their password in the database. Get the movie_id from the request. And today's date we all know. (You can also check for yesterday and tomorrow to avoid time-zone issues.)

Then you generate the same hash and compare it to the API_KEY that user sent you. If they match - all good.

This way you will end up with unique AJAX calls that are valid for one movie only and will expire in about a day.

I think that would be a pretty efficient approach, at least business-wise.

Comment: The right way to do this is using HMAC. Using regular hash functions to authenticate messages is not cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 1):

instead of having all the data in the url, why not use the POST method, and have all the data sent behind the scenes. you could then post their id and other data between pages (using hidden fields) or using a session.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull cookies in a web service. The web server then can use the authentication cookie to authenticate the web service call.  I'm sure what ever frame work your using has an authentication token stored in a cookie on the browser somewhere and there's a snipet of php somewhere to authenticate it.

**Danger not a php example here.**
  I have an authenticated web service on my web site http://www.gosylvester.com that just returns a hello world but if you put a trace on it and sign in.  You'll see the authentication cookie go up and down with it.

Your welcome to play around with the web service.  There's a button on the main page that says "ASP authenticated Test Button It says hello unless you are signed in"  put a trace on your browser and click it.

user guest password abc123$

You can also log in via webservice on my site but that's another post
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it secure, use [Oauth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication (2-legged variant, for your case). Of course, you could also use HMAC authentication, or key exchange, as other authors suggested, but it's always a better idea to use existing and verified protocols, not invent your own.

See:

- [Securing REST APIs](http://www.middlewareguru.com/mw/?p=366)
- [Using Oauth to protect internal REST API](http://tatiyants.com/using-oauth-to-protect-internal-rest-api/)